# Function with errors in numerical integration

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm looking for a function that generates significant errors in numerical integration using Gaussian quadrature or Simpson quadrature.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Damian! You don't need to sign your posts with your name, it is appended at the end of every post automatically (please read the FAQ!). The question isn't quite the best fit for Stack Overflow, you might want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Since Simpson's and Gaussian's methods are trying to fit a supposedly smooth function with pieces of simple smooth functions, such as 2nd-order polynomials, and otherwise make use of low-order polynomials and other simple algebraic functions such as $$a+5/6$$, it makes sense that the biggest challenges would be functions that aren't 2nd order polynomials or resembling those simple functions.

- Step functions, or more generally functions that are constant for short runs then jump to another value.  A staircase, or the Walsh functions (used for a kind of binary Fourier transform) should be interesting.  Just a plain simple single step does not fit any polynomial approximation very well.
- Try a high-order polynomial.  Just x^n for a large n should be interesting.  Maybe subtract x^n - x^(n-1) for some large n.  How large is "large"?  For Simpson, perhaps 4 or more.  For Gaussian using k points, n>k.   (Don't go nuts trying n beyond modest two digit numbers; that just becomes nasty calculation apart from any integration.)
- Few numerical integration methods like poles, that is, functions resembling 1/(x-a) for some neighborhood around a.  Since it may be trouble to deal with actual infinity, try pushing it off the real line, or a complex conjugate pair.  Make a big but finite spike using 1/( (x-a)^2 + b) where b>0 is small. Or the square root of that expression, or the sine or exponential of it.  You could replace the "2" with a bigger power, I bet that'll be nasty.

Once upon a time I wanted to test a numerical integration routine. I started with a stairstep function, or train of rectangular pulses, sampled on some set of points.

I computed an approximate derivative using a Savitzky-Golay filter.  SG can differentiate numerical data using a finite window of neighboring points, though normally it's used for smoothing.  It takes a window size (number of points), polynomial order (2 or 4 in practice, but you may want to go nuts with higher), and differentiation order (normally 0 to smooth, 1 to get derivatives).

The result was a series of pulses, which I then integrated.  A good routine will recreate the original stairstep or rectangular pulses.  I imagine if the SG parameters are chosen right, you will make Simpson and Gauss roll over in their graves.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a difficult function to integrate as a test method, you could consider the one in the CS Stack Exchange question:

[Method for numerical integration of difficult oscillatory integral](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5093/method-for-numerical-integration-of-difficult-oscillatory-integral)

In this question, one of the answers suggests using the [chebfun](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23972-chebfun) library for Matlab, which contains an implementation of a basic [Levin-type method](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23972-chebfun/content/chebfun/examples/quad/LevinIntegrate.m). This suggests to me that the function would fail using a simpler method such as Simpsons rule.